# page not found in Chrome, but found in Firefox

Tags: 404-error

I use [.html on PAGES plugin](http://www.introsites.co.uk/wordpress/html-on-pages-plugin.html), and this works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.

However, Internet Explorer displays "page cannot be found".

Why would one browser not display a page, but two others find it?

Problem pages are:

- http://tech.doig.com.au/testimonials.html
- http://tech.doig.com.au/portfolio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a very confusing response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 20 Oct 2012 12:33:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
X-Pingback: http://tech.doig.com.au/xmlrpc.php
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

After that the regular page content follows.

So in your first line you tell the browser to look elsewhere for the content. But you don’t say where, there is no `Location` header. And then you send the content?

Fix the HTTP header: send a proper status code (`200`), or a `Location` header with an URL for the new address.

Comment: Thanks toscho.  What tool did you use for this?  I have an .htaccess file (http://pastebin.com/RLUutcgA) which redirects portfolio.html, but only if the host is steve.doig.com.au, not tech.doig.com.au (I once moved my web design site from steve.doig.com.au to tech.doig.com.au).

Comment: @Steve I hit `Ctrl Shift i` in Opera. [Screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/g2Kv4.png). I don’t think it is a `.htaccess` problem. There is probably a broken plugin calling [`wp_redirect()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_redirect/) without `exit` afterwards. Disable all plugins and check again.

Comment: Thanks, I found the Network tool in Chrome too.  I disabled all plugins, refreshed the page, and the network tool shows there is still a 301 redirect on portfolio.html.

Comment: Then it is a result of the way the _.html on PAGES_ plugin works. Looking at the code I see it does almost everything wrong it can do. Find a better plugin.