# 404 or ugly page on IE, but Firefox, Chrome looks perfect

Tags: headers, browser-compatibility

I have a variation of [this issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69904/page-not-found-in-ie-but-found-in-chrome-firefox).

Was happening before and after new theme.  I was getting 404 in IE, now sometimes get partial page that looks horrible. Contents can vary when I refresh.

I have no idea why it's giving a 404 status.  Is that the way WordPress handles domain/com/blogs?  I have a page called Blogs, and my "Reading Settings" for "Posts Page:" is set to "Blogs".  I use a plugin called "WP Code Highlight" but have tried deactivating it and other suspect plugins.

Below are my Request/Response Headers:

```
Remote Address:97.79.239.229:80
Request URL:http://biztalk-training.com/blogs/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview parsed
GET /blogs/ HTTP/1.1
Host: biztalk-training.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/21.0.1432.57 (Edition Campaign 48)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,lzma,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=194928574.1923935199.1399605602.1399605602.1399605602.1; __utmb=194928574.3.10.1399605602; __utmc=194928574; __utmz=194928574.1399605602.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 09 May 2014 03:22:26 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Pingback:http://biztalk-training.com/xmlrpc.php
```

I get similar results when I go to most any [specific blog](http://biztalk-training.com/blogs/view-biztalk-cumulative-updates-installed-control-paneladd-remove-programs/)

My .htaccess file contains just this one line:

> ErrorDocument 404 /

I tried removing it, then got some default page provided by my ISP.

Comment: as far as I can tell, every page on your site is returning a 404 in every browser. this is definitely not normal behavior, you have an issue with some plugin/theme or server configuration.

Comment: Okay, so how do I isolate and debug? What tools/techniques to use.  If it is getting 404, then how can the page ultimately show in FireFox?

Comment: Your site is redirecting to a affiliate site that you are getting paid for. Considered spam as flagging as such

Comment: Pieter - While you were reading/trying my link, I had just tried changing my .htaccess and that's what happened (that's my ISP's default redirect page), I reset it back, and now it's back to the original issue.

Comment: your content appears correct, it's just getting the 404 header erroneously sent along with it. status codes are just header data sent along with a page, that's how you can have nice 404 pages styled by your theme. I would start by disabling all plugins and switching to a core-bundled theme to see if the issue is within WordPress.